# Bootstrap Justified Nav Bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I made a justified navigation bar with this code:

```
         <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Seite 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seite 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

And this js Code:

```
$(".nav ul li").on("click", function(){
   $(".ul").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

But when I click on the Items in the list, they are greyscaled but there isnt this line around them, do anyone know how to fix it?
Best regards Azoni

Edit: It should look like the left one but looks like the right one:http://imgur.com/a/2RSvJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to select an `ul` inside an element with class `.nav` which itself is the `ul`. In addition, you're adding the class to the wrong element, the parent of the `li` which is the `ul` instead of the `li`. Moreover, you can just remove it from all instead of first finding the only active one.

I.e. do this:

```
$(".nav li").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```